# just only one list on my listview

Tags: android

I have array look like this :

```
"results":[
     {
        "code":"jne",
        "name":"Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)",
        "costs":[
           {
              "service":"OKE",
              "description":"Ongkos Kirim Ekonomis",
              "cost":[
                 {
                    "value":38000,
                    "etd":"4-5",
                    "note":""
                 }
              ]
           },
           {
              "service":"REG",
              "description":"Layanan Reguler",
              "cost":[
                 {
                    "value":44000,
                    "etd":"2-3",
                    "note":""
                 }
              ]
           },
           {
              "service":"SPS",
              "description":"Super Speed",
              "cost":[
                 {
                    "value":349000,
                    "etd":"",
                    "note":""
                 }
              ]
           },
           {
              "service":"YES",
              "description":"Yakin Esok Sampai",
              "cost":[
                 {
                    "value":98000,
                    "etd":"1-1",
                    "note":""
                 }
              ]
           }
        ]
    }
]
```

My code on android to process array, problem in my code on function "for" before I copy and edit another code from file :

```
JSONObject jsonObjsko  = new JSONObject(rajaongkir);
String resultse        = jsonObjsko.getString("results");

JSONArray jsonObjssto  = new JSONArray(resultse);
JSONObject mJsonObject = jsonObjssto.getJSONObject(0);
costs                  = mJsonObject.getString("costs");

JSONArray jsonArray    = new JSONArray(costs);
for (int k = 0; k < jsonArray.length(); k++) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArrayp  = new JSONArray(costs);
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArrayp.getJSONObject(k);
        String serviceq       = jsonObject.getString("cost");
        String servicel       = jsonObject.getString("service");

        kon  = String.valueOf(jsonArray.length());
        kin  = kin + k;

        JSONArray jsonObjsstorng  = new JSONArray(serviceq);
        JSONObject mJsonObjectrng = jsonObjsstorng.getJSONObject(k);
        String values             = mJsonObjectrng.getString("value");
        ShipPerActiv wp           = new ShipPerActiv(servicel, values);

        arraylist.add(wp);
    } 

    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code for ShipPerActiv for add arraylist :

```
public class ShipPerActiv {
    private String services;
    private String hongkir;

    public ShipPerActiv(String services,String hongkir) {
        this.services = services;
        this.hongkir = hongkir;
    }

    public String getservices() {return this.services; }
    public String gethongkir() {return this.hongkir; }
}
```

I tried use harddebug with `kon` & `kin` `true` function for normal but not on my listview just one int(0) not int(1)~etc

Comment: I am not getting your question clearly. Can you explain again properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first convert your StringObject to `JSONObject` and dont forget to add `{` at first of string and `}` to end of string:

```
 JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject("{"+"JsonString"+"}");
```

Then parse your object like this :

```
try {
     JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(a);
     JSONArray results = parentObject.getJSONArray("results");
     JSONObject resultsObject=results.getJSONObject(0);
     JSONArray costsArray = resultsObject.getJSONArray("costs");
        for (int i = 0; i < costsArray.length(); i++) {
                Log.d("CostsJsonObject" , costsArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());
            }
} catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("CostsJsonObject Exception" , e.toString());
}
```

And result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is on this code :

```
JSONObject mJsonObjectrng = jsonObjsstorng.getJSONObject(k);
```

Simply change it to :

```
JSONObject mJsonObjectrng = jsonObjsstorng.getJSONObject(0);
```

Hope it'll help you ;)